# Time-trigger fires only when editor is viewing the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The custom function which I've set the time-trigger fires only when I or other editor is logged in and viewing the sheet and does not fire when the sheet is closed. What am I missing?

Comment: Provide proof of this accusation.

Comment: Please take a look at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GMtVgB8oloC2Lr-xHEeiiYK_yjFnNraicNmoopaUDrE/edit#gid=1988184194

Comment: It's more likely that the trigger is actually firing, but for some reason only returns the expected result when the Sheet is open.  A trigger will most likely either fire or not.  It's extremely unlikely that the trigger only fires when the Sheet is open.  I'm not saying that it couldn't happen, but if that's the case it would be a bug, and you'd need to file an issue report.  But for this problem, I wouldn't assume that it's a bug until you do the work to get more information.  You need to troubleshoot the situation.  We can't do that for you.

Comment: While a link to a demo spreadsheet could be useful, the question should include all the required details to be answered. Add a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: There is a time-trigger which should fire the function which updates the URL in sheet 'Wyniki', column E (for now it's cell E13 but will go forward). Then the currentscore of the match should appear.

There are few users logged in but until I or other editor logs in there is no change in formula, so the function doesn't fire. There are no errors reported and the trigger fires automatically only when I open the sheet and each 5 minutes as set before. When I close the document, the function stops firing.

Comment: If it's true that the trigger only fires when the Sheet is open, then it's an internal issue to Apps Script.  Only a Google Engineer could fix that problem.  You'd need to document the exact steps that reproduce the problem and file an issue on the Issue Tracker.  So, it would be a bug.  We can't fix a bug.  But again, you need to prove it.  It *does* happen, that there are bugs that affect very few people, and no one has determined how to reliably reproduce the problem.  But Stack Overflow isn't for filing bug reports.

Comment: Script editor> view>executions. Did it fire at the right time?

Comment: Set notifications on the trigger to immediate you might be getting an error and not know it.